# Qt Designer custom checkbox relative path

Tags: python, qt, checkbox, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

I am trying to make a Checkbox in Qt Designer that uses custom png images instead of the checkbox.

I do this by using a custom stylesheet with following content:

```
QCheckBox::indicator {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 }

QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
 image: url(radio_selected.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked
{
  image: url(C:\\MYPROJECT\\subdirectory\\radio_unselected.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked:hover
{
  image: url(C:\\MYPROJECT\\subdirectory\\radio_selected.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:hover
{
  image: url(C:\\MYPROJECT\\subdirectory\\radio_unselected.png);
}
```

The absolute paths using dual backslashes deliver the desired result. The relative path entry doesn't work.
Neither does

```
QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
 image: url(./radio_selected.png);
}
```

nor

```
QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
 image: url(.\radio_selected.png);
}
```

nor

```
QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
 image: url("radio_selected.png");
}
```

nor

```
QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
 image: url(file:///radio_selected.png);
}
```

or anything else that i've tried... what am I missing here?

Comment: Please make sure that the working directory in which your application is running is set to `"C:\MYPROJECT\subdirectory\"`

Comment: I can't find any option for setting a working directory in Qt Designer. As for the python script with which I call the *-ui file, it's set to run in its appropriate directory.

Comment: Okay... Could you try some other relative paths, like `..\\radio_selected.png`, `subdirectory\\radio_selected.png`, `..\\subdirectory\\radio_selected.png` etc.? And you could try to use the ui file in an actual program, running in the appropriate working directory, to test if maybe designer uses a wrong / unexpected working directory.

Comment: Ah and the usual syntax for URLs in QSS is `"some/file/path"`, i.e. a quoted string with just forward slashes. Please also try `"./radio_selected.png"`.

Comment: ok, the `"./radio_selected.png"` seems to have done the trick if I call the UI file from the python script - Qt Designer won't show the image with a relative path. I'm sort of OK with it as long as it's working in the final Script - still pretty annoying. Thanks, leemes!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, although you don't have an optimal solution. Maybe the problem can be solved, but I'm no expert in Qt Designer. You could try the [mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/interest), the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/), or the [IRC channel](http://wiki.qt.io/Online_Communities) to ask for help. The last link also contains links to other communities you could try... Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, when using the Qt designer with custom QSS, if you want your image labels to be in a relative path to the *.ui file, one has to use the syntax
`./radio_selected.png` to make it work.

It won't show in the editor, but it will work when calling the *.ui file from a script.